# How to do a teardown of pytest intermediate results on test fail?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

There is enough information on how to setup and share pytest fixtures between tests.

But what if a test would create some remote resources and then fail? How to make pytest to cleanup those resources which haven't existed as fixtures at test beginning?

Comment: Use a fixture with a `yield` statement. Code below the yield is cleanup code.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a variable in class level

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("run_for_test")
class TestExample:

    __some_resource = None

    @pytest.fixture
    def run_for_test(self):
        set_up()
        yield
        if self.__some_resource:
            self.__some_resource.cleanup()

    def test_example(self):
        self.__some_resource = SomeResource()
```

Comment: thanks, @Guy! will this work in case the ```__some_resource``` that is the class ```SomeResource``` is a Singleton?
Also what I do not understand, if tests are executed in a random order, how to ensure that test_example() would create the resource before the test_anonther_example()?

Comment: @J.Doe Yes, it will work. You wrote in your question the resources are created in the tests, but if it's singleton the order doesn't really matter anyway.